# Where can I ask about languages that don't have a dedicated site?

Tags: support, questions, site-recommendation, scope, languages

As an avid fan of folk, metal and especially folk metal, I encounter many foreign languages and dialects on a daily basis. As I would like to understand what I'm hearing to the best of my ability as an English-only speaker, it would be very convenient if I didn't have to propose a new site on Area 51 every time I'm confused about a lyric. Unfortunately, it looks like SE prefers sites for individual languages as opposed to groups of languages, and Google Translate is not a native Swede, nor does it translate Sognamål.

Where can I ask this kind of question so that native speakers and cultural experts will see it?

P.S. I really don't think the folks over at Music Fans would be able to help much with translation stuff.